# mpeg packetized stream into transport stream

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

I have some questions related to the multiplexing of mpeg PES streams (packetized) into mpeg TS.

Why the DTS and PTS value are included in the PES header and PCR value in the transport stream header?

What if we want to play somehow just PES stream then we have no PCR value needed for playout?

If the PCR is created by multplekser (ts header) not encoder, then how multplekser know the corelation with PTS,DTS of the coded stream ?

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 2):

PCR values are included in TS for the purpose of time synchronization between encoder and decoder. Hence decoder can lock its clock to encoder's clock.

On the other hand, PTS/DTS values are related to the time of presentation/decoding of the specific presentation unit (PU). Theoretically, decoder don't have to take into account PCR values and manage presentation/decoding of PUs solely based on PTS/DTS values.

See [this](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/rd/pubs/reports/1996-02.pdf) for further details.